# Excel VBA highlight only cell in row 2 of current column while scrolling

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write an excel code that will highlight, while scrolling though, the cell in the second row of the same column as the active cell. So, if I had "B56" selected, I would want "B2" highlighted.

I've been trying to modify this code, to no avail:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
End Sub
```

*courtery of https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2913-excel-highlight-whole-row-when-scrolling.html

That script highlights the whole row. I've figured out how to make it do the whole row, the whole column, or both, but I can't seem to limit it to the second row of the active column only.

Help?

Comment: Try `Me.Cells(2, Target.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`EntireColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.entirecolumn):

```
Target.EntireColumn.Rows(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 8
```